# Using complex th:attr fields with Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template with a rather complex `data-` attribute, like so:

```
<div data-dojo-props="required: true, placeholder:'Foo bar baz', more: stuff" ...>
```

I'd like to have Thymeleaf provide the placeholder, like so:

```
<div th:data-dojo-props="placeholder:'#{foo.bar.baz}'" ...>
```

It doesn't work, of course. I'm supposed to use `th:attr` like so:

```
<div th:attr="data-dojo-props=placeholder:'#{foo.bar.baz}'" ...>
```

Which also doesn't work. As soon as you add a `:` or `'` within the `th:attr`, the template breaks. I also tried escaping them, e.g. `\:` and `\'`, and also tried using HTML entities, e.g. `&38;`, but also didn't work.

So I tried `th:prependattr` and `th:appendattr`:

```
<div th:prependattr="data-dojo-props=placeholder:'"
     th:attr="data-dojo-props=#{foo.bar.baz}"
     th:appendattr="data-dojo-props='"
...>
```

But they also can't handle `:` and `'`, nor escaping them:

```
<div th:prependattr="data-dojo-props=placeholder&58;&39;"
     th:attr="data-dojo-props=#{foo.bar.baz}"
     th:appendattr="data-dojo-props=&39;"
...>
```

Any way to make this work that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameters in a Thymeleaf message property for example:

**Messages.properties:**

```
dojo.props=required: {0}, placeholder: {1}, more: {...}
dojo.props.required=true
dojo.props.placeholder=Foo bar baz
```

**HTML with message properties:**

```
<div th:attr="data-dojo-props=#{dojo.props(#{dojo.props.required}, #{dojo.props.placeholder})}"></div>
```

**Or if you want to get the values from a object:**

```
<div th:attr="data-dojo-props=#{dojo.props(${dojo.props.required}, ${dojo.props.placeholder})}"></div>
```

**Even selectors work:**

```
<div th:attr="data-dojo-props=#{dojo.props(*{dojo.props.required}, *{dojo.props.placeholder})}"></div>
```